Как загрузить частичное представление несколько раз?
Добавляю частичное представление через кнопку:
async function GetPartialView() {

    console.log("GetPartialView functoin work!!")

    $("#Mytbody").load("/SummaryPlanning/GetPartialViewForVarTexProcess");

    // работает, но добавляет только одну строку,... как добалять две строки три и тд при нажатии на кнопку...

}

НО, частичное представление добавляется лишь один раз, как мне добавлять столько раз сколько я нажму на кнопку?
Частичное представление представляет собой строку таблицы

Нужно вместо load использовать обращение к серверу другим способом и добавлять данные уже через append. Пример:
$.get('/SummaryPlanning/GetPartialViewForVarTexProcess', function(data) {
    $("#Mytbody").append(data);
});

